# Does google maps api support "suggestions"?

Tags: google-maps

Does google maps api support "suggestions" ?

In other terms, can I receive from google maps the suggestions given a submitted query ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Geocoding API, which according to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) will return multiple results:

> Generally, only one entry in the
>   "results" array is returned for
>   address lookups, though the geocoder
>   may return several results when
>   address queries are ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the maps api autocomplete which will return suggestions for locations
[Google Maps API Places Auto Complete](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#places_autocomplete)